# csv header naming convention to import products with multiple categories and images in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, import

I am trying to import products through system->import/export option. I have created a custom attributes also.

While creating the csv file some attributes are having underscore prefix. For example type is as _type, _product_websites etc. Some of them are not having the prefix.

If I change _type as type it is not working.

How can I decide the attribute should have underscore prefix or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first run an export, you can use the exported sheet as reference.

Simply modify the exported sheet, add new lines if needed, and re-import it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, for a category section a product belongs to primarycategory/secondarycategory . I created an csv category as primarycategory/secondarycategory . but onle secondarycategory  is selected in the categories tab.

Comment: @milan , what is the purpose of _ prefix, and how to remove